# how to remove "powered by zingchart" in angularjs piechart

Tags: angularjs, zingchart

Is there any way to remove "powered by zingchart" text in zingchart piechart ?

I saw some answers in web, that need to add license key.

Do we have any other way, without adding the license key ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it really is legal to remove a watermark without having a license key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
div[id$="license"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Tested [here](https://codepen.io/zingchart/pen/QjpgLg)

Still, this is a illegal way. Use a valid license key for legal and permanent usage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about how to violate our terms of agreement for using our product at https://www.zingchart.com/buy/. This is totally inappropriate and should be removed. More details on courses of action can be found at the following: https://www.zingchart.com/legal/